# Open multiple CSVs from a folder - split them by a value in column

Tags: loops, csv, import, split

I have hundreds of csv files in several folders. Each csv has 3 different catergories - say A,B,C. I need to open all the files in a particular folder and split based on column value - A B or C and create a new csv for each.

I seem to be going round in circles. I'm new to python, so as much help as possible would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us where u are struggling. So if your problem is on crawling through directories, u can use os.walk, example:

```
FOLDER = r'D:\Dir\yourfiles' 

def get_module_data():
    module_folder = os.path.join(FOLDER, 'data', 'modules')

    filenames = [os.path.join(module_folder, f) for f in
                  os.listdir(module_folder)]

    data = [parse_file(f) for f in filenames]

    return data
```

And CSV means Comma Seperated Values, so you have to read files line by line, and split from the commas, for that you can use split() function.

```
yourstring.split(",")
```

Then you can do whatever you want with these strings.